# app_fee_money in Payments API Not Supported in Japan?

Tags: square-connect

Using a Japanese account, I am currently able to successfully create payments using OAuth access tokens for our clients. If I try adding app_fee_money (100 JPY, same currency as amount_money), I get the following 400 error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "INVALID_LOCATION",
      "detail": "app_fee_money is not supported in your location.",
      "category": "PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the same result for both sandbox test account and our second account (different from the one that creates payments) in production mode.

Is app_fee_money not available in Japan? I was not able to find any info about supported regions for app_fee_money in the documents.

I am using square/connect 3.20200528.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately app_fee_money is currently only supported in US, UK, CA, and AU, not Japan currently.

Comment: I see. I hope it becomes available soon.